# Can't access field from opportunity contract lookup

Tags: apex, opportunity, lookup, contracts

In my trigger on Opportunity I am trying to access name field of contract on opportunities from newMap by opportunity.Contract.Name(There is a standard lookup Opportunity.ContractId). It returns null to me, but i know that it's not. May be it is because i can't access fields in a such way? I really don't want to use SOQL query here, any chance i can avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Parent and child relationships are not populated in the `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.newMap`, `Trigger.old`, and `Trigger.oldMap` properties. You only get the fields on the record itself, including any formulas. If you really wanted to avoid the query, you could use a formula field:

- Contract Account Name (Contract_Name__c) (Text)

  Contract.Name

Which you could use in your trigger:

```
for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
  String accountName = record.Contract_Name__c;
  // ...
}
```

---

Aside from that, you do need to query parent/child records to gain access to that data. This is usually done in an [Aggregate-Query-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html):

```
Map<Id, Contract> contracts = new Map<Id, Contract>();
// Aggregate
for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
  contracts.put(record.ContractId, null);
}
// Query
contracts.putAll([SELECT Name FROM Contract WHERE Id = :contracts.keySet()]);
// Update
for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
  String contractName = contracts.get(record.ContractId);
  // ... do stuff here
}
```